# Scala Find Method Syntax

Tags: scala

```
val underlying: MongoDBCollection
def find(doc: DBObject): DBCursor = underlying find doc
```

Here's a hypothetical program.  This is apparently a valid implementation of the `find` method, but I don't understand how the method body `underlying find doc` could produce a value.  How does the `find` method evaluate the `doc` parameter, and how is the `underlying` variable affecting anything?  Why not `find doc underlying` or just `find doc` as the method body?

Comment: Is your question about mongo or about scala?

Comment: Scala.  But it was answered.  The book I'm reading didn't mention the particulars of the syntax for this find method.

Answer (score 2):

When a method takes only one parameter, you can omit both the prefix `.` and the brace `()` when calling the method on an object.

```
underlying find doc
```

is the same as

```
underlying.find(doc)
```

It calls the `find` method on the `MongoDBCollection` instance `underlying`  with the `doc` as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

In MongoDB you can pass an object to the find function:

```
db.<collection>.insert({ "a": "aa"})
db.<collection>.findOne()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5516c37adedf9a4f8cffc7bd"), "a" : "aa" }
db.<collection>.findOne({ "_id" : ObjectId("5516c37adedf9a4f8cffc7bd"), "a" : "aa" })
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5516c37adedf9a4f8cffc7bd"), "a" : "aa" }
```

You could write the scala code like this:

```
val collection: MongoDBCollection
def find(doc: DBObject): DBCursor = collection.find(doc)
```

`find` is a function of `MongoDBCollection` and `underlying` is an instance of a collection (which should be initialized to point to some collection). `doc` is a MongoDB object that is passed to find as an argument.